# get value from control on VB form that was created on the fly

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net 2010. I am trying to create a semi-generic popup form, I successfully create the form and put values in labels and have a button (this is simplified, it will be more complex).  When I click the button I want to get a value from the popup form and put it in a label in the calling form.  I can't seem to "see" the labels or anything else that are IN the popup, its still a valid form, not yet disposed.  I can see the stuff in form1 (the calling form) of course, but not the popup, either with Me which returns "form1" or Form.Active which returns "insertPopup" so I would think it would work.  I can get it to work with many buttons and call sub's based on the buttons but the idea was multiple choices with checkboxes and on button, I can create the checkboxes but without being able to reference them or labels it wont work.

`
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    createPopup(Me, "next", "prior") 'this will place 2 values on the popup so we can make a choice
End Sub

Private Sub createPopup(callingFrmName As Form, Optional lblN As String = Nothing, Optional lblP As String = Nothing)
    Dim insertPopup As New Form
    'create the popup, set the size, center the screen
    insertPopup.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(300, 400)
    insertPopup.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    insertPopup.Name = "insertpopup"
    insertPopup.Show()

    'create buttons, labels, textboxes, etc.
    Dim acceptNextButton As New Button
    Dim acceptPriorButton As New Button
    Dim cancelButton As New Button
    Dim lblCallingForm As New Label
    Dim lblnext As New Label
    Dim lblprior As New Label

    'set the sizes, text and other parts of the controls
    lblCallingForm.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 25)
    lblCallingForm.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(185, 24)
    lblCallingForm.Text = "Calling Form Name : " & callingFrmName.Name.ToString

    lblnext.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 100)
    lblnext.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(185, 24)
    lblnext.Text = lblN

    lblprior.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 205)
    lblprior.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(185, 24)
    lblprior.Text = lblP

    acceptNextButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(200, 100)
    acceptNextButton.Text = "Insert"
    acceptNextButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 24)
    acceptNextButton.TabIndex = 1

    acceptPriorButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(100, 325)
    acceptPriorButton.Text = "Insert"
    acceptPriorButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 24)
    acceptPriorButton.TabIndex = 1

    cancelButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(190, 325)
    cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    cancelButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(85, 24)
    cancelButton.TabIndex = 2

    'now really create them, show them
    insertPopup.Controls.Add(lblnext)
    insertPopup.Controls.Add(lblprior)
    insertPopup.Controls.Add(lblCallingForm)
    insertPopup.Controls.Add(acceptNextButton)
    insertPopup.Controls.Add(cancelButton)

    'add Handlers so users can click on buttons.
    AddHandler acceptNextButton.Click, AddressOf acceptNextButton_Click
    AddHandler cancelButton.Click, AddressOf cancelButton_Click
End Sub
Private Sub acceptNextButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim callingForm As Form = CType(CType(lblCall, Label).Parent, Form) 'get the name of the calling form so we can put values back in.
    Dim frmInsertPopup As Form = Form.ActiveForm
    'Dim lblP As Object = Form.ActiveForm.lblprior.text 'NOPE, also tried insertpopup.lblprior.text

    Dim c As Control() = callingForm.Controls.Find("lblCall", True) 'find the control on the calling form set it. 
    If c.Count > 0 Then        'Check to see if we got a match
        CType(c(0), Label).Text = callingForm.Name.ToString
    End If 'this works to put FIXED values into calling form, fixed like "HELP" or the callingform variable  BUT NOT something from popup form

    Dim x As Control() = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("lblprior", True) 'NEVER FOUND
    If x.Count > 0 Then
        callingForm.Controls("Label2").Text = CType(x(0), Label).Text 'NEVER GETS HERE and I don't understand why not.
    End If

    'callingForm.Controls("Label2").Text = "This worked also"  
    'callingForm.Controls("Label2").Text = CType(Form.ActiveForm.Controls("lblprior"), Label).Text 'this does NOT work
    CType(CType(sender, Button).Parent, Form).Close()
End Sub`
```

Comment: Controls.Find search by name, you haven't named your controls.

Comment: DUH, I spent several hours on this.  Naming the controls worked DUH... THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method Find from the ControlsCollection search the controls using the control Name property. If you don't name your controls the Find method will fail

```
lblprior.Name = "lblprior"
lblprior.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 205)
lblprior.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(185, 24)
lblprior.Text = lblP

' Now this should work
Dim x As Control() = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("lblprior", True)
```

Comment: I was thinking that Dim lblprior As New Label gave the label the name, I know it does not but was not thinking correctly.  Once you said name it, I did it and it worked perfect.  Now on to the rest of the code. THANKS AGAIN